# Are there iOS apps for taking notes with Apple Pencil in color, grid, and with pages to print?

Tags: ios, ipad, software-recommendation, notes.app, apple-pencil

I am searching for an app, in which I can take notes during lectures. To be more specific I would like to find an app which extends the default notes app in the following ways:

1. *Creating a color palette* (eg. I would like to have darker colors, but it seems like I can only pick one color at a time)
2. *Changing grid size* (I would like to make the grid a bit smaller, so it fits my handwriting better)
3. *Option for pages* (Ideally I would like to be able to print my notes, but the $\infty$-paper cuts my handwriting in half)

Other features (like pdf annotation, text recognition etc.) are not important for my use case. The recommended apps I was able to test (Notes, INKredible, Nebo, Sketches, Paper, Quicknotes) didn’t fulfill these requirements. Due to cost I could not test Goodnotes or Notepad+.

I hope there is an app satisfying my needs, to specially to vouch for a paid app if that’s the only fit for my requirements.

Can any app do some or all of my requirements?

Answer (score 1):

[Notability](https://support.gingerlabs.com/hc/en-us/articles/206088327-Buying-Notability-for-iPad-iPhone-and-Mac) is the app you want to use but it is $8.99. There is also a version for Macs as well. This allows multiple colors and it opens with a large page to write on. I can't vouch for it because I use Notes but Notability is a popular app. You can read about it at the link I included.

There is a free app called [Notes Writer](https://www.noteswriter.com) which you could check out since it's free.